# Is there a way to return a whole different data structure by using mongodb aggregations and projections?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

Let's say I have the following mongodb collection with the following structure:

```
mongodocument:
   _id: xxx
    A: "CLEYMAR_COMPANY"
    category: Object
        ENGINEER: Object
        ARQUITECT: Object
```

Professions can be null based on company.

and I want to return a data structure based on the following query:

Return a result set based on categories  given a list of keys for A such as

```
["CLEYMAR_COMPANY", "VIC_COMPANY"]
```

and a list of categories such as

```
["ENGINEER", "ARQUITECT"]
```

result:

```
ENGINEER_RESULT :  [ENGINEER(corresponding to CLEYMAR COMPANY)      ENGINEER(corresponding to VIC_COMPANY)]

 ARQUITECT_RESULT: [ARQUITECT(corresponding to VIC COMPANY)].
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to autowire the mongo template.

```
@Autowired
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
```

- `$match` to match the companies
- `$addFields` to overwrite the category field. Since we have dynamic key as category in in category, we will make it to array with key value pairs using `$objectToArray`. Then filter the array with profession list. Once we filtered, it will give the array. To make it to original form, we use `$arrayToObject`

Since spring data doesnt provide any `$addFields`, we need to use [TRICK TO CONVERT MONGO SHELL QUERY INTO EQUIVALENT JAVA OBJECTS](http://pingax.com/trick-convert-mongo-shell-query-equivalent-java-objects/)

And the method is

```
public List<Object> test(List<String> companies,List<String> professions ) {

    Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
        match(Criteria.where("A").in(companies)),
        a-> new Document("$addFields",
                new Document("category",
                        new Document("$arrayToObject",
                            new Document("$filter"
                                new Document()
                                .append("input",new Document("$objectToArray","$category"))                     
                                .append("cond",
                                    new Document("$in",Arrays.asList("$$this.k",professions))
                                )
                            )
                        )                                       
            )
        )

    ).withOptions(AggregationOptions.builder().allowDiskUse(Boolean.TRUE).build());

    return mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(YOUR_COLLECTION.class), Object.class).getMappedResults();

}
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/T2kcWpc-Ao-)**

Note : The java code is not tested. It was written based on working mongo query

Comment: Hi Varman thanks for your answer. First question, what does new Document do?

Comment: Java documentation- A representation of a document as a Map. All iterators will traverse the elements in insertion order, as with LinkedHashMap.